# How do I get rid of the side bar in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sidebar

I am currently in the process of redesigning my company's brand space in order to make it more accessible and have a higher aesthetic appeal.

What I am trying to do is make our default page simply 4 hyperlink images of flags which will lead visitors for files for specific countries.

The main conflict is that I cannot find a way to get rid of the side bar on the left that contains the quick links to different areas of the Sharepoint site. I am looking to have a very basic lay out and we will not miss the functionality of the side bar.

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. One of them is given below:

http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-hide-left-side-navigation-on.html